# Should i use setters/getters in class I made them

Tags: c++, oop, encapsulation, getter-setter

> Car.h

```
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H

class Car
{
     public:
        void setColor(int color);
        void colorCarWithRandomColor();
     private:
        int _color;            
};

#endif
```

> Car.cpp

```
#include "Car.h"
void Car::setColor(int color){
   _color = color;
}
void Car::colorCarWithRandomColor(){
    // Imagine that there is a function called getRandomColor and that returns random color.
    _color = getRandomColor(); 
    // or
   setColor(getRandomColor());
   // which one is correct
}
```

So which one of these is better to use. `_color = getRandomColor();` or `setColor(getRandomColor());` in this case? Should i call `setColor` function or it is correct to directly change `_col`

Comment: @user `_color` is private

Comment: They're both valid and will probably be compiled to the exact same code. I think it might get confusing to start throwing your setters round in their declared class. Also `Car::setColor` appears to have no validation, assuming you've got a `Car::getColor` function and are not going to add validation to `Car::setColor` all the setters/getters do is destroy the encapsulation of `_color` you might as well not have bother with them at all.

Comment: @UnholySheep Indeed, sorry..long day

Comment: @Corey I just made up this for example. This is not code i am working on. I wanted just to ask whether i should access it directly or by setters and getters (in that same class).

Comment: This is only opinion... I'd use the getters/setters in general....  If you are trying to debug code later on down the line and want to know why a variable changed, it's easier to set a breakpoint in a sertter function then to set breakpoints in a bunch of places or try to do a data change breakpoint. IMHO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should prefer to write code which will be as immune as possible to future changes, that generally means using your own setter (and getter) rather than directly accessing your own private data.

For example, say you decide to change `_color` to be an `enum` or an RGB-tuple.  If you use `_color` directly, you'll have more places to change.  Using `setColor(int)` you have just one place to convert from `int` to whatever your new internal storage might be.

Furthermore, in your particular example, since `setColor` is `public`, your `colorCarWithRandomColor()` method might be able to be a non-member non-friend function which further decreases coupling.  (Of course, that depends on exactly how your `getRandomColor()` method works.)

```
void colorCarWithRandomColor(Car& car) {
    // Imagine that there is a function called getRandomColor and that returns random color.
   car.setColor(Car::getRandomColor());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly correct to directly refer to a variable within its own class.

The idea of accessors/mutators is that functions using the data outside the class should not make any assumptions about how it is stored.

Obviously the class itself knows how the data is stored so is free to manipulate it directly.